# Hyphenation with common prefixes

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

I'm struggling with a hyphenation problem. I'm writing the following sentence:

> This happens both in high- and low-tax countries
>    This happens both in high and low-tax countries
>    This happens both in high and low tax countries

Would the introduction of the word 'rate' make this any different:

> This happens both in high and low tax rate countries

More importantly (and more in line with the spirit of this Stack Exchange), what is the rule that drives this?

Comment: As an inhabitant of _the Low Countries_, I do get confused about the version without hyphens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules like this are established by style guides.

In [APA](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen.aspx), for example:

> When two or more compound modifiers have a common base, this base is sometimes omitted in all except the last modifier, but the hyphens are retained.
>
> - Long- and short-term memory
> - 2-, 3-, and 10-min trials

Following this rule, you would write:

> This happens both in high- and low-tax countries.